# Getting Data from database with Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, stored-procedures

Hello and thanks for reading.

I have a database that contains a Unique ID and Email. When I click a button I want to get all the Emails from the Database and display in my Textbox with id Emailliste.

If it works it should list all emails in the textbox with a , between them. Like this.
Email1@email.com, Email2@email.com

Here is my C# code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PCM13812;Initial Catalog=Newsletter;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "GetAllEmail";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = connection;

        connection.Open();

        string email = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        EmailListe.Text = email;

        connection.Close(); 
    }
```

Here is my script to create the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllEmail]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Email nvarchar(50)
SELECT @Email = COALESCE(@Email+ ', ', '') + Email
FROM Newsletter

END
```

Im not sure what Im doing wrong but i hope someone can help me

Comment: Does'nt a Function is more accurate to return data?

Comment: Im not sure, if you could give me an examble i would love it.

Comment: what problem you are facing

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an exception or is the SP result always null?

Comment: Sorry forgot to say thats the problem is, my bad. The problem is that nothing get displayed in the Textbox when i click the button.

Comment: Please share your buton click code

Comment: @Pawan My button code is the C# code you can see above.

Comment: @Dannydust My Textbox has the ID EmailListe.

Comment: @Mr. Anderson Yes I'm sorry I deleted my comment immediately, cause I noticed it shortly after commenting... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select `@Email` from your procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllEmail]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Email nvarchar(50)
SELECT @Email = COALESCE(@Email+ ', ', '') + Email
FROM Newsletter

-- You need do this
SELECT @Email
END
```

Comment: Thanks now it displays something, but it ONLY display the first 2 emails. not the 3'rd 4th and so on.

Comment: Try to increase the size of @Email variable

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure (if we're talking about MS SQL) is not actually returning a result, you are missing an output SELECT. With the current procedure you are only assigning a value to @Email variable.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllEmail]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Email nvarchar(50)
SELECT @Email = COALESCE(@Email+ ', ', '') + Email
FROM Newsletter

SELECT @Email --// this is missing, so the proc will actually return a result

END
```